# How to rotate camera around a sketch as it draws, without effecting the drawing

Tags: processing

Wondering if someone could help me, I am new to processing and programming in general.

I have created a random walker that walks a point around a 3D space. Please see code below.

Now I would like to be able to rotate the view of this walker as it is drawn, so I can view it from different angles. I have tried using PeasyCam to achieve this, but when I use the mouse to rotate the camera, it only affects the location of the new points, and not the previously plotted ones.

If anyone could let me know what I'm doing wrong that would be really helpful! Thanks, here is my code:

```
import peasy.*;

PeasyCam camera;

void setup() {
    size(500,500,P3D);
    background(0);
    camera = new PeasyCam(this, 0, 0, 0, 50);
}

void draw() {
    walker();
}

float x = 0;
float y = 0;
float z = 0;

void walker() {
    pushMatrix();
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(5);
    point(x,y,z);
    x = x + random(-2.5,2.5);
    y = y + random(-2.5,2.5);
    z = z + random(-2.5,2.5);
    popMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your previous points to be affected by the rotation, then you need to redraw them.

You could do this by storing all of the points in a data structure like an [array](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/arrays) or [ArrayList](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/arraylists). Then you'd iterate over the points and redraw them every frame.